# I want to change color of individual bar of bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, chart.js

I am getting data from mysql using php to populate the array and then using that result to fill chart data. I want to change the color of the bars which are greater than 50. I tried a few examples that are already on the stack-overflow, however I was unable to solve my problem. That is why I am now asking this question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/chartjs/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var player = [];
      var score = [];

      for (var i in data) {
        player.push(data[i].y);

        score.push(data[i].x);
      }


      var chartdata = {
        labels: player,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Records from mysql',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(92, 95, 102)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(30, 0, 200)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 197)',
            data: score
          }

        ]
      };



      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        colors: {
          data: function(score) {
            return (score.value >= 45) ? '#00ff00' : '#f90411';
          }
        },
        data: chartdata
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#chart-container {
  width: 640px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">
  <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: `myapp.js` is this your custom javascript file?

Comment: #Barrosy yes and i pasted it's code in the question

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with PHP then I suppose? It is probably not worth mentioning other languages if you do not have any question regarding those (refering to PHP). If I understand your question correctly, you would like to know how to add logic to the chart(s) of `chart.js` which tells: `if` value of given bar `>` 50 `then` turn bar to a red color?

Comment: I did some fiddling around with what `Chart.js` has to offer to get (what I think) whatever you are trying to achieve and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/347he28u/1/) would be the result. I will see if I could apply your code to it.

Comment: HI sorry for the late reply, okey i will keep it mind next time not to mention other language but the data that i can getting throught database using php and populating it the array using json

Answer (score 1):

From what I could figure out is that your question is mostly related to the usage of [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/). My solution to your problem would look like the following:

```js
//Load your data (obviously this is a hardcoded example, you could use any backend code like PHP):
let data = [12, 19, 74, 38, 45, 62];
//Insantiate fields you would like to use, such as `colors` for background color and `borderColors` for, you guessed it, the color of the borders:
let colors = [];
let borderColors = [];
//Set the field values based on value (this would be your logic):
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  //When the value is higher than 45, set it to given color, else make them the other color (in the example the bars would appear red-ish):
  if(value > 45) {
    colors[index] = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)";
    borderColors[index] = "rgba(0, 255, 1)";
  }
  else {
    colors[index] = "rgba(249, 4, 17, 0.2)";
    borderColors[index] = "rgba(249, 4, 17, 1)";
  }
});

//Any code related to creating the chart with the bars (you could find any documentation regarding this code on the homepage of Chart.js):
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Records from mysql',
            //Populate your fields here:
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: colors,
            borderColor: borderColors,
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(30, 0, 200)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 197)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#chart-container {
  width: 640px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdhf9r62/)

I applied some code I found on the [following post](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5302#issuecomment-369995454) on Github:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  //When the value is higher than 45, set it to given color, else make them the other color (in the example the bars would appear red-ish):
  if(value > 45) {
    colors[index] = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)";
    borderColors[index] = "rgba(0, 255, 1)";
  }
  else {
    colors[index] = "rgba(249, 4, 17, 0.2)";
    borderColors[index] = "rgba(249, 4, 17, 1)";
  }
});
```

If anyone knows a more clean solution, please let me know in the comments.